# Does a pronoun share the subject of a noun it is referring to?

Tags: english, pronouns, punctuation

I have been reading the Cambridge Dictionary punctuation guide (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/punctuation), and a couple of things struck me as queer. Especially the "Separating clauses with commas" section.

*Footballers these days earn more money but they are fitter and play many more matches.*

The guide says that clauses that have different subjects don't have to be separated by commas. Is it actually established that a pronoun ("*they*") shares the subject of a noun it is referring to ("*footballers*")?

Comment: I would say that they definitely **do not** have the same subject. Their subjects are _coreferential_, but they are clearly separate entities. Punctuation-wise, as the previous sentence shows, I would absolutely separate the two clauses with a comma. I don’t know what criteria CD are using to say it’s the same subject – presumably they’re talking about semantics rather than syntax.

Comment: Thank you. Nice example _in_ the explanation.